# Dynamically load JSON for ngMock httpBackend response in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ngmock, ngmocke2e

I'm building an ngMock httpBackend in a Protractor test.

```
var mockJson = require(projectRoot + 'mock/load.json');

var mockResource = function() {
    angular.module('aMockObject', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E'])
    .run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('a/path').respond(mockJson);
    });
};
```

The default JSON object for the mock response needs to be loaded from a file.

However, the $httpBackend code is actually executed in the browser context, not the Protractor script context, so the `mockJson` variable is undefined.

Is there any other way to make this work? All I could think of is some sort of injected script tag to load the json file in the browser context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data between protractor and your application with [addMockModule](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule):

**file.json**

```
{
    some_property: 'value'
}
```

**aMockObject.js:**

```
exports.module = function (data) {
    angular.module('aMockObject', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E'])
    .run(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenGET('a/path').respond(data);
    });
};
```

**The init function:**

```
var aMockObject = require('aMockObject');    
var file = require('file.json');    
browser.addMockModule('aMockObject', aMockObject.module, file);
```

Comment: Amazingly simple. Surprised I didn't come across this solution sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Well, loading the json directly works.

```
// Allow JSON
$httpBackend.whenGET(/.*\.json$/).passThrough();

$http.get('/path/to/file.json').success(function(json) {
  // other httpBackend code here
});
```